# Reused view in UIPickerVIew viewForRow: loses its subviews?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I'm attempting to re-use a view with subviews in a UIPickerView:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
            viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
           reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel* label = nil;
    if (view == nil) {
        view = [[UIView alloc] init];
        label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [view addSubview:label];
    }
    if (label == nil) {
        label = view.subviews[0]; // Exception here because there are no subviews
    }
    ...
```

If my "reusingView" UIView is set on entry, I'd expect it to have retained (literally as well as figuratively!) the subview I added, the UILabel. However, after setting up the first few on-screen views from scratch, I'm called with a (recycled, I assume) non-nil "reusingView", but it doesn't have any sub-views, so I'm crashing when trying to get its existing label to alter it.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to duplicate your problem. I made a simple project with the following code, which is very similar to yours. I added a frame to the label, and colored the background so I could see what was going on. Can you see any difference from what you have that would cause a difference in outcome (maybe the problem is in the "..." area that you don't show)?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.picker.dataSource = self;
    self.picker.delegate = self;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return 10;
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UILabel* label = nil;
    if (view == nil) {
        view = [[UIView alloc] init];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 22)];
        label.text = @"test";
        [view addSubview:label];
    }
    if (label == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@",view.subviews);
        label = view.subviews[0]; // I do get subviews here.
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That gave me the confidence that I wasn't misunderstanding the view recycling, but instead doing something else wrong. It turns out that if you expand the existing method to add a new view wrapped around your existing one, it helps to *return the new one you added, not the old one that is now inside it*. (The results that worked looked right because I was just wrapping the same label in an empty view while I got things working. D'oh!)

Comment: Always view is creating and entering into the first if condition what you added above.

Comment: @rdelmar - when using this approach -> view = [[UIView alloc] init]; in swift 3.0, I am getting an error: "cannot assign to value: 'view' is let constant". this is how I am doing: ---------  if let vv = view {
            return vv
        }
        view = UIView(frame: .zero)

Comment: link to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388853/uipickerviews-reusing-view-always-nil